# Open source tool list for monitoring SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

What good open source tools are available for monitoring SQL Server 2005?

Tools available within SQL Server which I have used in past

SQL Profiler
DMVs
Perfmon

Is there any 3rd party open source tool available like IDERA - Diagnostics or Quest - Spotlight which can help you to evaluate the health of your SQL Server

Comment: Improve your question by including what 'good' means, and what features you want to see in the tool. Performance monitoring, memory, CPU, page writes, index fragmentation, deadlock detection, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My company, SentryOne, puts out a free query plan analysis tool called Plan Explorer. You can read about it here:  https://sentryone.com/plan-explorer

And see this blog post showing off its many advantages over analyzing execution plans in Management Studio:

https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/plan-explorer-3-0-demo-kit/

Adam Machanic puts out a great little stored procedure called sp_WhoIsActive:

http://whoisactive.com

As for a full monitoring solution, there is an incredible amount of I.P. that goes into doing this - from collecting data efficiently to presenting it in a useful manner. So it is unlikely that you will find a comprehensive solution in the open source arena - but that shouldn't stop you from sniffing around at sites like CodePlex or GitHub.